# Is guard band used when bonding 20MHz channels together to form a 40+ MHz channels?

Tags: ieee-802.11

In IEEE 802.11n and above

Wi-Fi channels occupy 20MHz bandwidth over the spectrum, and it is a good practice to skip some channels as they may fall inside another's band, thus creating a sort of guard band.

When multiple 20MHz consecutive channels are bonded together forming 40, 80 and 160MHz channels, is the entire bandwidth utilized or is there still some gap between each 20MHz slice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From all the documentation I can see, the entire bandwidth range is used in a contiguous range to implement the wider channel slice (80Mhz etc.), which is why it will result in much improved theoretical throughput and also much increased interference in congested environments.

Some more good details here: https://www.networkcomputing.com/wireless-infrastructure/channel-bonding-wifi-rules-and-regulations

'Guard bands' are simply areas of the spectrum that are not used in normal deployments but the option to increase channel width steps on that feature because the assumption is that if you can afford to use the wider channel, you no longer need the guard band dead space at the traditional edges of the channel because the edges of the channel are now much wider. The guard bands would be moved out to the new edges of the wider channel.